# Is there a way to count total number of items defined in Enum?

Tags: go

I am trying to count the number of items defined in my enum (iota) in Go, but I am unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, `ILen` and `XLen`,

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
    I1 = 1 << iota
    I2
    I3
    ILen int = iota
)

const (
    X1       = "A"
    X2       = "B"
    X3       = "C"
    XLen int = iota
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(I1, I2, I3, ILen)
    fmt.Println(X1, X2, X3, XLen)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/krBVid3jLNq

```
1 2 4 3
A B C 3
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)
>
> [Iota](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Iota)
>
> Within a constant declaration, the predeclared identifier `iota` represents successive untyped integer constants. Its value is the index of the respective ConstSpec in that constant declaration, starting at zero.